# Wufoo is loading my stylesheet, but not displaying styles

Tags: css, wufoo

This is quite a strange problem I'm experiencing.  I've got a Wufoo form set up to load an external stylesheet.  Wufoo is doing this properly and I can find the `link` tag and follow the `href` of that tag to the actual link and view the source of the stylesheet I've uploaded.  So I know the stylesheet is indeed loading no problem (in fact, it's loading last), but not a single style is actually applied.

Right now I've even tried adding `!important` to my styles in an attempt to override the current styles.  I don't see the styles loading into Firebug either.

[Here's the link to the form.](https://goldenspiral.wufoo.com/forms/connect/)

[Here's the link to the stylesheet.](http://zanewilliams.goldenspiralcreative.com/wp-content/themes/goldenspiralcreative/_/css/wufoo.css)

The test I'm doing is in the latest version of Chrome to get the `input` and `textarea` tags to have a `border-radius` of 10px.

Comment: Seeing this in Chrome Dev Tools (looks like Wufoo is https and your stylesheet is served over http): [blocked] The page at https://goldenspiral.wufoo.com/forms/connect/ ran insecure content from http://zanewilliams.goldenspiralcreative.com/wp-content/themes/goldenspiralcreative/_/css/wufoo.css.

Comment: Right, but would this conflict in protocol be an issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking Wufoo to an external stylesheet without SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116193/linking-wufoo-to-an-external-stylesheet-without-ssl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that needed to happen was that I disable SSL for Wufoo because the protocol of my website isn't over secure HTTP.  Apparently my stylesheet was being loaded, but not correctly implemented.

[Here's more information on that from Wufoo.](http://help.wufoo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5782#format)

> By default, all accounts that are SSL enabled will have SSL forced
>   upon every form. In some settings, mainly due to browser
>   configuration, SSL is not desired. We can override SSL by slightly
>   modifying the URL for a form.